# Iframe issue in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am creating a dynamic iframe. In order to listen for 'blur' even on iframe I have made it work in FF and IE using iframe's contentWindow.document and iframe respectively. But this does not work in Google Chrome (May be not work in other webkit browsers). My question is I am looking for an event which can call my handler anytime user loses focus(Leaves Iframe)  from Iframe window. I don't have to access any content in iframe so question of security does not arise. Just an event to trigger whenever I lose focus from iframe and select any other control on web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) "Safari and Chrome don’t support [blur] on links and/or form fields in all circumstances."

You might have one of those circumstances where it's not supported.

if you're curious, follow the link and click on "blur" to read more about it.